# Which Python libraries to use for analyzing doc and docx files?

Tags: python, docx, doc

I am writing a doc and docx parser. It is necessary to obtain various metadata about the document of these formats. For example, for docx, I need to get the XML code and continue to work with the tags. Tell me the solutions that will help solve my problem? Solutions like python-docx are not suitable, because they work only with text.

Answer (score 1):

If you need raw `docx` data, you'll probably work with it low-level, i.e. open file with [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) and read meta with [xml etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)